# NUnit: Unit testing with complex object as test method parameter

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to perform a Unit testing on a controller method as below,

```
[TestFixture]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    static object[] TestData =
    {
        new object[] { new EmployeeAgreementRequest(), 1, 4 }
    };

    [Test, TestCaseSource("TestData")]
    public void AgreetoParticipate(EmployeeAgreementRequest employeeAgreementRequest, int brandID, int employeeID)
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.AgreeToParticipateInSP(employeeAgreementRequest, brandID, employeeID);
        var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Boolean>;
        NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
        NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(true, contentResult.Content);
    }
}
```

This method is not getting picked up, when i say debug tests. Please let me know what am i missing here.

Also please let me know if this the right way to run test method with multiple test data.

Visual studio output:

```
No tests found to run.
```

Comment: What are the NUnit related references (and NuGet packages) you used in this project? That matters a lot on whether VS can discover your test cases.

Answer (score 2):

The form of your source data is incorrect. A field marked with `[TestCaseSource]` is expected to contain an `IEnumerable` with each enumerated item forming a test case. In your code, the `object[]` provides the enumeration and contains **three separate test cases** with one argument each. Obviously that's not your intent, you only have one test case with three arguments.

If you were using a different runner, e.g. the console runner, you would see an error message for this. Because of how the Test Explorer works, you don't see one there although there is probably a log message from NUnit in the output window.

The correct form for your test case would be as follows:

```
static object[] TestData = new object[]
{
    new object[] { new EmployeeAgreementRequest(), 1, 4 }
};
```

or alternatively...

```
static TestCaseData[] TestData = new TestCaseData[]
{
    new TestCaseData( new EmployeeAgreementRequest(), 1, 4)
};
```

IMO, the second is much clearer to anyone reading your code.